# Почему переменная players1 принимает значение LEARNING.PROGRAM+User;

Tags: c#

В конечном итогде отображается игрок LEARNING.PROGRAM+User; имеет уровень 5, почему не Nick1? ;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LEARNINNG
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            User players1 = new User("Nick1");
            User players2 = new User("Nick2");
            LVL[] lvl = { new LVL(players1, 5), new LVL(players2, 1) };
            LeaderBoard leders = new LeaderBoard(lvl);

            leders.ShowLeaders();
        }

        class User
        {
            public string Name;

            public User(string name)
            {
                Name = name;
            }
        }

        class LVL
        {
            public User Igrok;
            public int level;

            public LVL(User user, int lvl)
            {
                Igrok = user;
                level = lvl;
            }
            public void showlevel()
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Игрок {Igrok} имеет уровень {level}");
            }
        }

        class LeaderBoard
        {
            public LVL[] PlayerLevel;

            public LeaderBoard(LVL[] levels)
            {
                PlayerLevel = levels;
            }

            public void ShowLeaders()
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < PlayerLevel.Length; x++)
                {
                    PlayerLevel[x].showlevel();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот у вас есть бумажка, на ней написано имя, фамилия, возраст, и прочее. Вы берете эту бумажку и. как вы ее воспримите? Как "Вася" или как "Бумажка с данными"? Вот в программировании тоже самое, у вас есть класс, внутри которого есть данные, вы пишете `Игрок {Igrok}`, то есть выводите просто класс как строку, вот вам и говорит "Это бумажка", то есть `LEARNING.PROGRAM+User` (путьДоКласса(Namespace)+НазваниеКласса). Конкретизируйте, запросите конкретное поле/свойство, которое хотите взять из класса, ну или переопределяйте `ToString()` у класса `User`.

Answer (score 0):

Всё понял свою шиз:)В классе LVL в функции showlevel в выводе в консоль нужно  $"Игрок {Igrok.Name} имеет уровень {level}" вместо $"Игрок {Igrok} имеет уровень {level}"

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставьте подробно описанные ответы. Чтобы редактировать ответ нажмите [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1488565/edit)